# @Capacitor/App-launcher opens webpage instead of app

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I have installed @capacitor/app-launcher in my ionic cordova project as @ionic-native/app-launcher is no longer usable after upgrading the angular version to 16.

I tested the plugin by trying to open basic apps on my emulator. Instead of launching the app, the plugin opens the package name through a webpage.

Here's the code I tested.

```
import {AppLauncher} from '@capacitor/app-launcher';

const packageName = 'com.android.calendar';
const {value} = await AppLauncher.canOpenUrl({url: packageName});
if (value) {
    AppLauncher.openUrl({url: packageName})
}
```

I also tested youtube, clock and other basic apps in my emulator. Instead of launching the app, it opens a webpage with the link http://localhost/com.android.calendar. I've read capacitor's documentation and followed youtube guides but my result doesn't seem to be the same. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: what apps do you want to open?

Comment: Have you tried this on a physical device? Simulators are not the same as a device in your hand.

Comment: @solimanware i want to open apps like teams, i have their package names already and i'm still testing them for now.

Comment: @StackoverBlows yes, i have tried it on my phone but got the same results as the emulator.